# Installing the Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch

Tags: 10.10, wacom

I would like to use the Wacom Bamboo "Pen & Touch" with Ubuntu Maverick and I don't have any idea how to do this. In addition, when I see "change or add kernel" I become really scared. :-)

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

I saw answers for the Wacom Bamboo "pen" but I don't know if the installation instructions are the same or if some different additions need to be made to my system.

Answer (score 3):

It should work out of the box. Just plug it in and you're good to go. You can test it out with the simple (yet powerful) program called "mypaint", available in the software center.

If it doesn't work (usually because it's a brand new piece of hardware) it's possible that you need to update the module for wacom tablets. You can do that by entering the following in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms
```

Restart your computer and plug in your tablet. It should work now.