# Installed Wacom Bamboo Pen + Touch drivers, but no dice

Tags: drivers, wacom, graphics-tablet, bamboo

I'm trying to install my new Wacom Bamboo Pen + Touch tablet in Ubuntu 10.10. As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24990/installing-the-wacom-bamboo-pen-touch), among other places, I've installed the Wacom dkms package by *doctormo* and rebooted my PC, but the tablet doesn't work.

**What works?**

The lights on the tablet, and it shows up in `lsbusb`.

**What doesn't**

Nothing else. There is no input. `xsetwacom list devices` gives emptiness.

**dmesg**

```
[  444.340133] usb 7-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 4
[  444.512012] usb 7-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 056a:00d6 Wacom Co., Ltd
```

Comment: Did you look at this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/11815/how-to-install-wacom-bamboo-pen  ?

Comment: @jgbelacqua: that seems to give the same instructions as in the link in his answer.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Thanks -- you're definitely correct (I missed that it was the same repo).  I'll leave the link though, because it has a few possibly relevant comments from @doctormo (and it's his repository).

Comment: Well, I just did the same procedure on another system (same Ubuntu version) and it just works, so there must be something wrong with my laptop.

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: Yeah, I didn't immediately accept it because I'm used from Stack Overflow that you can't do that until 2 days after you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. For some reason I was running an old Linux kernel (2.6.32-22). I've switched to 2.6.35-28 now and it works instantly.

It still needs some tweaking to get it as comfortable as in Windows (things like scrolling, [pressure sensitivity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34495/getting-wacom-bamboo-pen-touch-pressure-sensitivy-in-gimp)), but they are for other questions.

Comment: Just a thought, but pressure sensitivity isn't in all Bamboo tablets.

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: According to their specifications, mine should have it: http://www.wacom.eu/index2.asp?pid=294&lang=en&spid=16

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: I also found out pressure sensitivity works out-of-the-box in blender, so it looks like an issue in GIMP.