# Getting Wacom Bamboo Pen + Touch pressure sensitivy in GIMP

Tags: input-devices, wacom, gimp

I've installed my Wacom Bamboo Pen + Touch (CTH-460) in Ubuntu (at least [on one system, not another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34167/installed-wacom-bamboo-pen-touch-drivers-but-no-dice)) and the pen works well for controlling the mouse cursor. However, I can't get pressure sensitivity to work in GIMP.

I have 4 extra devices in the input devices settings screen now, two of which are the pen and eraser. I've set them both from **Disabled** to **Screen**, and left the default settings intact.

[image: Input Devices settings screen]

However, after saving I still don't see any pressure options in the brush tool's options.

I've also tried setting the mode to **Window** instead, but it makes no difference regarding pressure sensitivity. There are no other modes.

The pressure works out-of-the-box in Blender (grease pen) so it must be something in GIMP.

What can be wrong? Why don't the options appear? How can I debug this?

Comment: For me, pressure sensitivity works with a Wacom tablet in Gimp 2.6.11. Have you made sure to check some boxes in "Brush dynamics" in the Tool Options menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly a bug in Gimp and should be reported:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

If the wacom support works in other programs then it's certainly not device related and everything you've done is correct.

Comment: It's fixed now, in Gimp 2.8 (and probably before)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution is not so obvious:
Switching the default behaviour from "Pen Pressure" to "Basic Dynamics" on the Tool Options panel worked fro me.