# Wacom Bamboo Capture CTH-470 Pen and Touch not working

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, wacom

I am trying to get my new Bamboo Pen&Touch tablet to work on ubuntu.

I tried following the guide on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24990/installing-the-wacom-bamboo-pen-touch); I installed and updated the wacom-dkms package, and nothing.

I followed the guide on [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562); I upgraded the xf86-input-wacom package, and ran all the commands in Appendix 1: still nothing.

I know that Ubuntu recognizes it, because when I run "lsusb" it shows up as
"Bus 005 Device 003: ID 056a:00de Wacom Co., Ltd "

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? If I can't get it to work, it's not a *huge* deal, because it works just fine on Windows. It would make things a lot easier if I don't have to keep OS-hopping, though--especially with Windows' long boot times... :-}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The build instructions in the linked forum post are working, but not if you combine it with the PPA method. The PPA of doctormo contains outdated sources which won't work for your CTH-470 Pen & Touch.

When following the instructions from Appendix 1, you will have to run it each time your kernel updates against the new kernel. Using DKMS is recommended which will automatically create the kernel modules each time your kernel is updated. I've made the updated packages available on `ppa:lekensteyn/wacom-tablet` (see also [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/6969))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lekensteyn/wacom-tablet
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms
```

On 15 April 2012 I've added an upstream patch for supporting the Cintiq 24HD, published for Oneiric and Precise (version 0.12.1-0ubuntu1~ppa4).