# How do I get my Bamboo Capture tablet working?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, wacom, graphics-tablet, bamboo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wacom Bamboo Capture CTH-470 Pen and Touch not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88028/wacom-bamboo-capture-cth-470-pen-and-touch-not-working)

As far as I know, only the first generation Wacom Bamboos work out of the box. But I use a third generation one (a bamboo Capture to be exact) what must I do to get a working driver?
If it helps, I'm using the x64 edition