# Wacom Bamboo Pen CTL 470 not working in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wacom, bamboo

I have an HP dv laptop running ubuntu 11.10 and gnome 3 DE. I've gone through a couple of posts here and followed the instructions given in this thread on ubuntu forums - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562

This is the instruction given in the troubleshooting part of the thread(because nothing else worked for me)

```
cd Desktop

git clone git://linuxwacom.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/linuxwacom/input-wacom

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install build-essential libx11-dev libxi-dev x11proto-input-dev xserver-xorg-dev libxrandr-dev libncurses5-dev autoconf libtool

sudo apt-get upgrade

uname -r

(If you have the generic kernel which most do.)
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

(If you have the rt or pae kernel.)
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-rt
or
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-pae

cd input-wacom

./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr

(If you are in Lucid or Maverick.)
sudo cp ./2.6.30/wacom.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko
or
(If you are in Natty or Oneiric.)
sudo cp ./2.6.38/wacom.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko

sudo depmod -a
```

I just can't get the `sudo depmod -a` part given in the instructions to work. When I do that, my output is like this -

```
gaya3@kikyo:~/Desktop/input-wacom$ sudo cp 2.6.38/wacom.ko /lib/modules/3.0.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/input/tablet
gaya3@kikyo:~/Desktop/input-wacom$ sudo depmod -a
WARNING: Can't read module /lib/modules/3.0.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko.gz: Exec format error
gaya3@kikyo:~/Desktop/input-wacom$
```

Also, my tab is detected as shown by running lsusb

```
gaya3@kikyo:~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 008: ID 056a:00dd Wacom Co., Ltd
```

I don't know whether I messed up by doing the instructions over and over again. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get a compressed kernel module in your modules directory? Remove it with:

```
sudo rm /lib/modules/3.0.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko.gz
```

The easiest way to install the drivers for this tablet is using the PPA mentioned in [Wacom Bamboo Capture CTH-470 Pen and Touch not working](https://askubuntu.com/q/88028/6969)