# How to make the Wacom Bamboo Splash Pen CTL-471 work on Lucid Lynx 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, wacom, bamboo

I've tried many sites and none of them have worked thus far. 
When I plug my Wacom Bamboo Splash Pen (CTL-471), the tablet lights up and it responses to the pen, but nothing is working. No response from my computer when I move the pen over the active area. How can I get it to work?

I'm using the Ubuntu Lucid Lynx 10.04 with the version 2.6.32-46-generic kernel.
When I type in lsusb, it shows up as " Bus 004 Device 006: ID 056a:00dd Wacom Co., Ltd ".

Update (Apr 30, 2013)
I tried lekensteyn's way:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lekensteyn/wacom-tablet
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms
```

Everything worked until I entered  sudo apt-get update. The terminal starts spitting out lines until it reaches an error:

```
    ... Hits and Igns ...
    Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages                               
    404  Not Found
    Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages                               
    404  Not Found
    Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org lucid Release
    Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org lucid/free Packages
    Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org lucid/non-free Packages
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/irie/wacom/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  
    404  Not Found

    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lekensteyn/wacom-tablet/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  
    404  Not Found

    E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then I tried to go to Software Sources and add the APT line ppa:lekensteyn/wacom-tablet and nothing happened. The window for adding the APT closes and I'm left staring at the SOftware Sources window. I tried restarting and nothing changed.

I'm at a lost now.

Comment: Have you reviewed some of this related post? [How to install Wacom Bamboo Pen](http://askubuntu.com/q/11815/62483) - [Wacom Bamboo Capture CTH-470 Pen and Touch not working](http://askubuntu.com/q/88028/62483) - [Wacom Bamboo Pen CTL 470 not working in 11.10](http://askubuntu.com/q/103283/62483)

Comment: I have. But, some of the things are different. Like the ubuntu version and the tablet version. I tried doctormo's before.

Comment: @Andrew The doctormo PPA is older (March 2011). Try my PPA in the other linked questions.

Comment: @Lekensteyn [Is it this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88028/wacom-bamboo-capture-cth-470-pen-and-touch-not-working)?

Comment: @Lekensteyn I tried the one that was linked above, but then I got an error.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with 10.04 LTS becoming an [EOL release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Version_end_of_life) on May 9th, since the recent release of 13.04. Since the packages and everything were moved (/will be? I'm not exactly sure when this happens) to an archive, away from the normal server your terminal is trying to contact, the normal methods of updating/installing don't work.

So the only real suggestion we can give on this site (since [we don't deal with EOLs](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)) is: Upgrade to a supported version. The best method is to do a [fresh install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest) with a LiveUSB/CD, but [upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04) should work as well.

See [this article](http://pogidude.com/2013/how-to-install-packages-for-end-of-life-ubuntu-editions/) if you still *really* want to stay on 10.04 and install software.