# How to set up a WACOM Cintiq 24 HD?

Tags: drivers, wacom

I'm new to Ubuntu and the Linux world (switched from mac to linux) and i have a problem: I'm studyin industrial-design and a lot of my work depends on my wacom cintiq 24 HD.

My problem is that ubuntu doesn't find my cintiq. I googled for wacom drivers and found the linux wacom project. The problem for me is that i hardly understand anything of what i have to do... Is there anyone who can tell me how i can set up my 24HD or is there an easy way for people who are new to linux like me.

I really really like linux and want to stay with it but that isn't possible for me without my cintiq. I would be very greatefull for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wacom Bamboo Capture CTH-470 Pen and Touch not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88028/wacom-bamboo-capture-cth-470-pen-and-touch-not-working)

Comment: hey. thinking on changing from windows to ubuntu, and I'm doing a lot of work with my wacom cintiq tablet too. Could you tell me if this has worked out well for you? Can you synch your tablet with your pc the same way you would on windows (mac?). Any issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone who has the same problem and needs a solution: i found it out myself.
You must update to linux **kernel 3.3.0** to get initial support for the cintiq 24HD.

I found a guide how to install the new kernel without having it to compile yourself:

This guide will help you install Linux 3.3 Kernel under Ubuntu 12.04/11.10 or older.

For Ubuntu (i386 / 32-bit):

Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
    $ cd /tmp && wget -O linux-headers-3.3.0-030300_3.3.0_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3-precise/linux-headers-3.3.0-030300_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_all.deb

    $ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.3.0-030300_3.3.0_all.deb

    $ cd /tmp && wget -O  linux-headers-3.3.0-generic_i386.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3-precise/linux-headers-3.3.0-030300-generic_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_i386.deb

    $ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.3.0-generic_i386.deb

    $ cd /tmp && wget -O linux-image-3.3.0-generic_i386.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3-precise/linux-image-3.3.0-030300-generic_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_i386.deb

     $ sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.3.0-generic_i386.deb
```

For Ubuntu (amd64 / 64-bit)

```
    $ cd /tmp && wget -O linux-headers-3.3.0-030300_3.3.0_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3-precise/linux-headers-3.3.0-030300_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_all.deb

    $ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.3.0-030300_3.3.0_all.deb

    $ cd /tmp && wget -O linux-headers-3.3.0-generic_amd64.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3-precise/linux-headers-3.3.0-030300-generic_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_amd64.deb

    $ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.3.0-generic_amd64.deb

    $ cd /tmp && wget -O linux-image-3.3.0-generic_amd64.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3-precise/linux-image-3.3.0-030300-generic_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_amd64.deb

    $ sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.3.0-generic_amd64.deb
```

After you finish, reboot your system

```
    $ sudo reboot
```

To check updated Linux kernel

```
    $ uname -r
```

The output will show you the upgraded kernel.

**WARNING**
Please upgrade the kernel at your own risk because it may render your system unstable. Additionally, upgrading kernel may cause problems with some installed proprietary drivers of NVIDIA / ATI (AMD) graphics cards, broadcom wireless etc., so be cautious!

Now everything works the way it should be! =)

Answer (score 0):

I received an email from Wacomm.
Dear Raul,

Thank you for contacting Wacom Support. The Ubuntu 16, is the Operating System right? Please be aware the Wacom tablets are just compatible with Windows and Mac OSX. Please let me know if that works for you or if is there something else that I can help you with.

Gabriela 
Customer Support Team
WACOM
855-MY-WACOM (855-699-2266)
http://www.wacom.com/en-us/support

Comment: While informative this does not answer the original question: *How to set up a WACOM Cintiq 24 HD?*, so it should have been posted as a comment instead of an answer.