# wacom bamboo intuos 5 PTK-450 is not detected on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: drivers, wacom

I own a **Wacom Bamboo intuos 5 model PTK 450** and would like to know how I make it work on **Ubuntu 11.10**. I am a Linux newbie,so it would be wonderful to have a step-by-step answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are a "Linux newbie", I suggest you to upgrade to the latest stable version of Ubuntu (12.04 Precise, a [LTS version](https://askubuntu.com/q/16366/6969)). After that, upgrade the kernel module that drives the Wacom tablet as mentioned in [Wacom Bamboo Capture CTH-470 Pen and Touch not working](https://askubuntu.com/q/88028/6969). 11.10 Oneiric does not have a recent Xorg driver that supports your tablet, you really need the xserver-xorg-input-wacom package from Precise and later.

For advanced material and background, refer to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562